# Class from installed gem not recognized by model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-geocoder

Within model `Venue` I am storing location data as a [Geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) object, which is acquired via `Geocoder.search` from a text input when a `Venue` is created. The location data object, which is of class `Geocoder::Result::Google`, is serialized and saved in a `text` column in the `venues` table.

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base

    serialize :location
    before_validation :get_location

    def get_location
        return false unless venue_text
        self.location = Geocoder.search(venue_text).first
    end

end
```

When I first create an object in Rails console

```
2.3.0 :001 > Venue.create(venue_text: 'Madison Square Garden, New York City, New York')
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "venues" ("venue_text", "location", "time_zone", "name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["venue_text", "Madison Square Garden, New York City, New York"], ["location", "--- !ruby/object:Geocoder::Result::Google\ndata:\n  address_components:\n  - long_name: '4'\n    short_name: '4'\n    types:\n    - street_number\n  - long_name: Pennsylvania Plaza\n    short_name: Pennsylvania Plaza\n    types:\n    - route\n  - long_name: Manhattan\n    short_name: Manhattan\n    types:\n    - political\n    - sublocality\n    - sublocality_level_1\n  - long_name: New York\n    short_name: New York\n    types:\n    - locality\n    - political\n  - long_name: New York County\n    short_name: New York County\n    types:\n    - administrative_area_level_2\n    - political\n  - long_name: New York\n    short_name: NY\n    types:\n    - administrative_area_level_1\n    - political\n  - long_name: United States\n    short_name: US\n    types:\n    - country\n    - political\n  - long_name: '10001'\n    short_name: '10001'\n    types:\n    - postal_code\n  formatted_address: 4 Pennsylvania Plaza, New York, NY 10001, USA\n  geometry:\n    location:\n      lat: 40.7505045\n      lng: -73.9934387\n    location_type: APPROXIMATE\n    viewport:\n      northeast:\n        lat: 40.7518534802915\n        lng: -73.99208971970849\n      southwest:\n        lat: 40.7491555197085\n        lng: -73.9947876802915\n  place_id: ChIJhRwB-yFawokR5Phil-QQ3zM\n  types:\n  - establishment\n  - point_of_interest\n  - stadium\ncache_hit: \n"], ["time_zone", "America/New_York"], ["name", "Madison Square Garden"], ["created_at", "2017-03-26 02:46:47.808170"], ["updated_at", "2017-03-26 02:46:47.808170"]]
   (12.4ms)  commit transaction
 => #<Venue id: 1, name: "Madison Square Garden", team_id: nil, venue_text: "Madison Square Garden, New York City, New York", location: #<Geocoder::Result::Google:0x00000003994dc0 @data={"address_components"=>[{"long_name"=>"4", "short_name"=>"4", "types"=>["street_number"]}, {"long_name"=>"Pennsylvania Plaza", "short_name"=>"Pennsylvania Plaza", "types"=>["route"]}, {"long_name"=>"Manhattan", "short_name"=>"Manhattan", "types"=>["political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1"]}, {"long_name"=>"New York", "short_name"=>"New York", "types"=>["locality", "political"]}, {"long_name"=>"New York County", "short_name"=>"New York County", "types"=>["administrative_area_level_2", "political"]}, {"long_name"=>"New York", "short_name"=>"NY", "types"=>["administrative_area_level_1", "political"]}, {"long_name"=>"United States", "short_name"=>"US", "types"=>["country", "political"]}, {"long_name"=>"10001", "short_name"=>"10001", "types"=>["postal_code"]}], "formatted_address"=>"4 Pennsylvania Plaza, New York, NY 10001, USA", "geometry"=>{"location"=>{"lat"=>40.7505045, "lng"=>-73.9934387}, "location_type"=>"APPROXIMATE", "viewport"=>{"northeast"=>{"lat"=>40.7518534802915, "lng"=>-73.99208971970849}, "southwest"=>{"lat"=>40.7491555197085, "lng"=>-73.9947876802915}}}, "place_id"=>"ChIJhRwB-yFawokR5Phil-QQ3zM", "types"=>["establishment", "point_of_interest", "stadium"]}, @cache_hit=nil>, time_zone: "America/New_York", created_at: "2017-03-26 02:46:47", updated_at: "2017-03-26 02:46:47">
```

I can immediately get the location object

```
2.3.0 :002 > Venue.first.location
  Venue Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "venues".* FROM "venues"  ORDER BY "venues"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
 => #<Geocoder::Result::Google:0x0000000b71bed8 @data={"address_components"=>[{"long_name"=>"4", "short_name"=>"4", "types"=>["street_number"]}, {"long_name"=>"Pennsylvania Plaza", "short_name"=>"Pennsylvania Plaza", "types"=>["route"]}, {"long_name"=>"Manhattan", "short_name"=>"Manhattan", "types"=>["political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1"]}, {"long_name"=>"New York", "short_name"=>"New York", "types"=>["locality", "political"]}, {"long_name"=>"New York County", "short_name"=>"New York County", "types"=>["administrative_area_level_2", "political"]}, {"long_name"=>"New York", "short_name"=>"NY", "types"=>["administrative_area_level_1", "political"]}, {"long_name"=>"United States", "short_name"=>"US", "types"=>["country", "political"]}, {"long_name"=>"10001", "short_name"=>"10001", "types"=>["postal_code"]}], "formatted_address"=>"4 Pennsylvania Plaza, New York, NY 10001, USA", "geometry"=>{"location"=>{"lat"=>40.7505045, "lng"=>-73.9934387}, "location_type"=>"APPROXIMATE", "viewport"=>{"northeast"=>{"lat"=>40.7518534802915, "lng"=>-73.99208971970849}, "southwest"=>{"lat"=>40.7491555197085, "lng"=>-73.9947876802915}}}, "place_id"=>"ChIJhRwB-yFawokR5Phil-QQ3zM", "types"=>["establishment", "point_of_interest", "stadium"]}, @cache_hit=nil>
```

But if I exit from Rails console and do the same thing, the class is undefined.

```
2.3.0 :001 > Venue.first.location
  Venue Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "venues".* FROM "venues"  ORDER BY "venues"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
ArgumentError: undefined class/module Geocoder::Result::Google
```

I thought that since the `geocoder` gem is installed on my application, the application should be able to recognize and define the classes and methods that come with the gem. Indeed, I was able to use `Geocoder.search` with no problems in my `get_location` method. What am I missing here?

Comment: Is the Geocoder gem loaded with `require: false`?

Comment: No. Geocoder methods like `Geocoder.search` work as expected with no issues.

Comment: What Rails version are you using?

Comment: I am using `Rails 4.2.5`

Answer (score 0):

Ruby deserialization is probably bypassing the `const_missing` method that Rails overrides to do its magic. Have you tried just adding `requires 'geocoder'` at the top of your file?